# Why does my discord bot give me error trying to make a slash command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been working on discord bot on nodejs and am trying to make a command which after you enter you get prompted a screen where you can type and when you send that text it gets send to another channel using a webhook.

The bot goes online and i can type the command. When i do it gives me error saying "the application did not respond".

Here is the full code to make it as easy as possible to reproduce this error.

```
// Configs
const token        = '';
const webhook      = '';
const clientId     = '';
const guildId      = '';
const webhookToken = '';
const webhookId    = '';

// Imports
import Discord from 'discord.js';
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { Routes } from 'discord-api-types/v9';

const { Client } = Discord;
const client = new Client({
    intents: 32767 
});
const MessageActionRow = Discord.MessageActionRow;
const MessageButton = Discord.MessageButton;

// Login
client.login(token)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Bot logged in successfully!');
  })
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  console.error('Unhandled promise rejection:', error);
});

// The problem
const commands = [{
  name: 'apply',
  description: 'Start your application!',
}] 

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
  try {
    await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  console.log(interaction);
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const { commandName } = interaction;

  if (commandName === 'apply') {
    const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('submit_application')
                .setLabel('Submit')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
        );

    await interaction.reply({ content: 'Your application questions go here', components: [row], ephemeral: true });
  }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand() && !interaction.isButton()) return;

  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'submit_application') {
      const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient({ id: webhookId, token: webhookToken });

      webhook.send({
        content: 'New application',
        embeds: [application],
      });

      await interaction.reply({ content: 'Your application has been submitted!', ephemeral: true });
    }
  }
});
```

I have deleted my node_modules and reinstalled them.
I updated every depency.

Comment: what does `console.log(interaction);` show in the console?

Comment: @Elitezen https://pastebin.com/qAS9LcbM it was too long to post.

Comment: You said that you have updated all the dependencies. So please check the discord.js version and please tell me

Comment: Discord.js version is 14.11.0

Comment: Your code is outdated! It looks like you're using `discord.js v13`. Please check [updating from v13 to v14](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start)